# Determine number of screens and screen relative location without WinForms

Tags: wpf, multiple-monitors

I want to save and restore the window position of my WPF application. I want to make the code robust to use with multiple monitors who's number and relative location can change (I want to avoid opening my application off-screen when the monitor configuration has changed inbetween invocations).

I know of the Screen class in System.Windows.Forms, but I don't want to take a dependency on that assembly just for this feature.

Answer (score 1):

Windows will keep your application on the screen even if you use corrdinates which are now outside fo the viewable range.  Just persist `DesktopLocation`, `Size`, and `WindowState` (to see if the app was maximized).  Be sure not to save these settings if the app was closed when minimized.

Comment: DesktopLocation is in System.Windows.Forms. I am looking for a solution for WPF instead. I can persist and restore Left, Top, Width, and Height, but when I restore them Left is not respected (i.e., negative values are not pushed to the left of the main screen).